# Computer BSOD on cold boot. Works fine off manual restart from BSOD? CPU fan not spinning at startup?

Tags: windows, bsod, fan

```
I think the title explains it all
Running win 7 
Gigabyte Mobo
X6 1055t
4gb ram  passes memtest86+
Good PSU
And yes the cpu fan header is connected. 

Is it just a bad install?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPU fan not spinning is a really bad sign.  I'd say the motherboard is defective.  OS has nothing to do with it.  Have you checked for a MB Bios update?

AMD CPUs will fry quickly (less than a minute) without CPU fan.  Unless you're sure your CPU has thermal shutdown circuitry I'd find another motherboard - pronto.

Comment: The Cpu fans spins after 2-3 seconds. it has a CM 212+ hooked to it. its a 1055t and 890GPA-UD3H.

Comment: It seems like its too bad of an issue. But thanks anyway!